# VLOOKUP for [First Word + First 2 Letters After Space]

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I've been fiddling around with this `VLOOKUP` for quite some time and haven't been able to crack it. I'm trying to match names from different data sources with names I have. So most of the time we will have the name in our system, but it could be spelled a different way. Therefore, I want to run a `VLOOKUP` function that will match on the first word of the name + the next 2 letters after the space.

Example:

[image: see image for example]

I've found out that I can isolate the first word by doing a `VLOOKUP` with `LEFT` and `FIND` in order to isolate the first word before a space.

`=VLOOKUP(LEFT(B19,FIND(" ",B19)-1)&"*",[report1554766140823.csv]report1554766140823!$A:$J,2,FALSE())`

I've provided two examples in the image: One instance where it **works** (Row 19), and one instance where it **doesn't work** (Rows 21, 22, 23).

You can see that it works in row 19, but in rows 21, 22, 23 it is pulling a different name with the first word 'American'.

I was wondering if I can concatenate a `VLOOKUP` of the **first word & first 2 letters of second word** using a formula to the extent of:

`=VLOOKUP(LEFT(B19,FIND(" ",B19)-1)&(RIGHT(B19,FIND(" ",B19)+2),[report1554766140823.csv]report1554766140823!$A:$J,2,FALSE())`

Would this be possible?

Comment: If it's *always* two characters after the space that you want, change `(LEFT(B19,FIND(" ",B19)-1)` to `(LEFT(B19,FIND(" ",B19)+2)`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Oh of course! Thank you. However, I'm intrigued by the conditionals that you eluded to. What were you thinking?

Comment: Why are you appending "*" to the string to look up?

Comment: @Nivi, this method will never works since for Lookup value you have Formula with VLOOKUP but the Range you are trying to extract the match has Full name so that Formula returns #NA error !!

Comment: @AlexM because I don't want an exact match. I want to match _as far as_ first word + first two letters of the second word. I'm assuming that that will be enough.

Comment: @AlexM Essentially I want to 'fuzzy match'

Comment: Got it. Well, @cybernetic.nomad wrote your answer. Just use a large enough `LEFT` chunk of the company name to ensure that the lookup is unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(B19,FIND(" ",B19)+2)&"*",[report1554766140823.csv]report1554766140823!$A:$J,2,FALSE())
```

You should only append -1 as +2 you want to extend after space char by +2 not minusing it.